# Python Trouble with Kolmogorov-Smirnov test non 'norm' distribution

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I am sure the answer is simple but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I want to test whether some sample data I have can come from a generalized extreme value or pearson type 3 distribution.

For some reason I cannot get `kstest(t1, 'genextreme')` to cooperate. However when I change it to `norm` it works.

See part of the code and error below:

```
from scipy.stats import kstest
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
import numpy as np
import csv


In [7]: from scipy.stats import genextreme

In [8]: t1 = TP['flow']
...: test_GEV = kstest(t1, 'genextreme')
...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-8-ebc8faf10381>", line 2, in <module>
  test_GEV = kstest(t1, 'genextreme')

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 3585, in kstest
    cdfvals = cdf(vals, *args)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1642, in cdf
args, loc, scale = self._parse_args(*args, **kwds)

TypeError: _parse_args() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)


In [9]: t1 = TP['flow']
...: test_GEV = kstest(t1, 'norm')
...: 
In [10]: test_GEV
Out[10]: (0.99999925980208981, 0.0
```

so it appears that it works for `norm` but not `genextreme`
... how to I get `kstest()` to work for other distributions besides `norm`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the ***function to generate random variables*-(kstest DocString)**

So for your example:

```
test_GEV = kstest(t1, scipy.stats.genextreme.rvs)
```

And for any distribution in scipy_stats call dist_name:

```
test_ks = kstest(your_array,scipy.stats.dist_name.rvs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`genextreme` has a shape parameter `c`, so you must use the `args` argument of `kstest` to fully define the distribution.  `genextreme` also has the standard `loc` and `scale` parameters that all the scipy univariate distributions have.  If you don't use `args` to specify these, the default values 0 and 1, respectively, are used.  It is up to you to choose the parameters `c`, `loc` and `scale` of the `genextreme` distribution against which you are testing `t1`.

To be fully explicit about the distribution you are using, you should use something like:

```
c = 1.0
loc = 0.0
scale = 1.0
test_GEV = kstest(t1, 'genextreme', args=(c, loc, scale))
```